# Changing TextBox Text of Form1 From Form2

Tags: vb.net, forms, showdialog

This is my problem...
I have a form (Form1), which is calling another form(Form2). In this Form2, when I close the Form, I want to call a method of Form1, to change values from Form1 components. The method is called, but the components values of Form1 don't change... I guess this is because when I call the method of Form1 from Form2, it is created anothed Form1 instance, and the method it's not executed in Form1 from which I call Form2
Form1 calling Form2

```
Private Sub btnCallForm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCallForm.Click
    frmForm2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Form2 calling method of Form2

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
   frmForm1.ChangeValues()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the original instance of `Form1` to the constructor of `Form2`, like this:

```
Public Class Form2 Inherits Form
    Dim theForm1 As Form1
    Public Sub New(form1 As Form1)
        theForm1 = form1
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
        ' Call instance of Form1 passed in to change the values here
        theForm1.ChangeValues()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now in `Form1`, when you create the `Form2` instance you need to pass the instance of `Form1`, like this:

```
Dim frmForm2 As New Form2(Me) 
frmForm2.ShowDialog()
```

---

> Note: `Me` is a reference to the current class, `Form1` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not passing any values back in ChangeValues(), then simply call it **after** the ShowDialog() line.  Then Form2 doesn't need to know about Form1 at all!...

Form1 calling Form2, then updating **itself** afterwards:

```
Private Sub btnCallForm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCallForm.Click
    frmForm2.ShowDialog() ' <-- code stops here until frmForm2 is dismissed
    Me.ChangeValues() ' <-- we're already here, update the values!
End Sub
```